# How can I use more than one if statement with only one else statement in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a very simple program but I ran into a problem with my `if/then` statement. A very simplified version of the code I was using is as follows:

```
print "What's your name?"
name = raw_input()
if name == 'Bob':
    print "Hi Bob."
if name == 'Mary':
    print "Hi Mary."
else:
    print "I don't know your name."
```

If I enter 'Bob' it prints "Hi Bob." followed by the else statement (which is the problem), but if I enter 'Mary' it doesn't print the else statement. I tried adding the `else` statement after each `if` statement, but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong? How can I use more than one `if` statement if there is only one `else` statement?

Comment: @DSM I wanted to verify that that was the OP's intent before posting an answer. I was waiting for them to comment back. Someone already posted it as an answer though, so I'll just delete the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `elif` like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print("What's your name?")
name = raw_input()
if name == 'Bob':
    print("Hi Bob.")
elif name == 'Mary':
    print("Hi Mary.")
else:
    print("I don't know your name.")
```

Python Tutorial on control flow:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

EDIT: Use print() in portable Python 2/3 way.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, put parentheses around print.  I edited my answer and it should work on both Python 2 & 3.